# Xubuntu automatically boots into initramfs [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due Errata

Tags: linux, initramfs, intel, xubuntu, firmware

The full error text given is

```
[        0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due Errata;
please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later).
```

What I could find in a similar question is to update my Intel microcode with `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`, the problem is that I can't do that within `initramfs`. I can't find anyway to get inside my system and do this update.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: That error shouldn’t prevent you from booting; are there no other errors?

Comment: That's the only error mentioned when I get thrown into initramfs. If I try the command "exit" I do get another error" Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems: ..." And then I also receive the alert" ALERT! UUID=.... does not exist. Dropping to a shell!" And then I am back where I started.

Comment: When running "dmesg|grep -I error" I get 2 errors "ACPI Error : thread ... Cannot release mutex [PATM] acquired by thread...". And " ACPI Error : Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCIO.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER"

Comment: I suspect the real reason you’re dumped to the initramfs prompt is the absent root device. You need to either figure out why that’s happening, or [edit] your question to include all the messages you’re seeing...

Comment: The error occurred when my BIOS settings were changed during an update, I answered my question to highlight this. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The source of my problem was that the BIOS had updated and in the process reverted my settings back to using RAID, which was causing me this boot error. Going into my BIOS and changing back to the previous settings solved my issue.